# Как оставить оригинальные цвета в NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Всем доброго времени суток
Не могу оставить оригинальные цвета в NavigationBar
Хотел бы чтобы логотип был цветным, а не монотонным как устанавливается в Tint
Получается вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А хотелось бы чтобы логотип был таким 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let iconName =  ...
let image = UIImage(named: iconName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self. onBarButtonItemTapped))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

alwaysOriginal вы можете в принципе выставить в инспекторе assets catalog.